# What is this scoop found on the core of a PW1127G engine near the CC/turbine section?

Tags: airbus-a320, engine-design, geared-turbofan

The view is back to front, the scoop is at 10 o'clock on engine 1. What would be it's function? I need supportive literature as well if possible.

[image: Pw1127G eng. View aft to fwd, scoop at 10 o clock on eng 1]

Answer (score 5):

That scoop allows air to go through the Engine Air/Oil Exchanger which cools the engine oil with fan bypass air.

Engine oil that is cooled by the air/oil heat exchanger decreases the quantity of heat that must be moved from the oil to the fuel in the fuel/oil heat exchanger.